# does we have to add database connceting codes in every cog?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, discord.py

```
cluster = MongoClient("link")
databse = cluster["aditya"]
Arson = databse["Economy-db"]
```

**we all know that we use this code To connect to the database but my question is let's see  I am using cogs, I added this in my Warn command cog, and now I need to fetch warn from the database in another cog , do I have to add a similar code in every cog where I am bound to bring data from this database?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py How to initialize database connection when running bot startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72193019/discord-py-how-to-initialize-database-connection-when-running-bot-startup)

Comment: I will not recommend to create a new connection in each cog. Instead, you should create a new attribute on your client, as example in your main file (bot is your `commands.Bot` object) : `bot.database = MongoClient()` then in your cog you will access to your MongoDB with `self.bot.database`

Comment: @paul i am not able to understand can you clarify more in a form of answer